# How To Make a URL for a Video in Flask that Works with HTML?

Tags: python, html, flask, html5-video, sendfile

I have a flask server that has a video file in it. How do I make it so users can watch the video using the HTML `<video>` tag? In the server, I have `send_file`:

```
@app.route("/movie")
def movie():
    return send_file("Images/i0.mov")
```

Then, in HTML I have:

```
<video width="90" height="90" controls>
  <source src="/movie" type="video/quicktime">
  Uh oh! Your browser doesn't support the <code>video</code> tag.
</video>
```

However, no video plays and I don't get the `Uh oh!` message. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I get:

```html
<html>

<video width="90" height="90" controls>
  <source src="/movie" type="video/quicktime">
  Uh oh! Your browser doesn't support the <code>video</code> tag.
</video>
<br><br>
It just doesn't load!
</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? What version?

Comment: @Abdur-RahmaanJanhangeer Google Chrome, `Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build)`

Answer (score 3):

Use `send_file` to download a file from the flask.  I have a similar case, where I passed the video file name as a variable.

Add url_for and pass the file in your HTML file

```
<video width="800" height="450" controls>
  <source src="{{url_for('static', filename=file)}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

and the backend,

```
@app.route('/video/<file>')
def video(file):
    return render_template('stream.html',file=file)
```